# SML - Recursion of inserting a value and creating a list in a list

Tags: list, sml, ml

I'm trying to do the following:

```
fun help(L)=if null(L) then nil else hd L::help(tl L);

fun inseach(a,L)=if null(L) then [[a]] else (a::L)::help(inseach(a,tl L));

inseach(4,[1,2,3]);
```

It needs to return: [[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,3,4]]

What I'm getting is:

```
val help = fn : 'a list -> 'a list
val inseach = fn : 'a * 'a list -> 'a list list
val it = [[4,1,2,3],[4,2,3],[4,3],[4]] : int list list
```

I want to change the command:

```
help(inseach(a,tl L))
```

to:

```
help((hd L)::inseach(a,tl L))
```

So it appends the head to each list I'm building, but I get errors every time.  I can't figure this out.  I'm sure there is something simple and obvious I'm missing.  I've had 15 of these things and this is the last one to solve.

Comment: What's the point of `... else hd L::help(tl L)`? You might just as well simply return `L` In this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry at one point in the inseach the inseach(a,tl L) I passed hd L instead of a.  Just trying to get this thing working.  I understand the concept of inserting the a value between the head and tail between each iteration.  I'm just having a hard time figuring the code out.

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it on my own.